# using php preg_replace to prepend the src values regardless how badly formed the img element is

Tags: php, regex

My html content looks like this:

```
<div class="preload"><img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/like_icon_u10_normal.png" width="1" height="1"/><img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/read_icon_u12_normal.png" width="1" height="1"/><img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/line_u14_line.png" width="1" height="1"/>
```

It is one unbroken long line with no newlines separating each img element with no indentation whatsoever.

The php code I use is as follows:

```
/**
 *
 * Take in html content as string and find all the <script src="yada.js" ... >
 * and add $prepend to the src values except when there is http: or https:
 *
 * @param $html String The html content
 * @param $prepend String The prepend we expect in front of all the href in css tags
 * @return String The new $html content after find and replace. 
 * 
 */
    protected static function _prependAttrForTags($html, $prepend, $tag) {
        if ($tag == 'css') {
            $element = 'link';
            $attr = 'href';
        }
        else if ($tag == 'js') {
            $element = 'script';
            $attr = 'src';
        }
        else if ($tag == 'img') {
            $element = 'img';
            $attr = 'src';
        }
        else {
            // wrong tag so return unchanged
            return $html;
        }
        // this checks for all the "yada.*"
        $html = preg_replace('/(<'.$element.'\b.+'.$attr.'=")(?!http)([^"]*)(".*>)/', '$1'.$prepend.'$2$3$4', $html);
        // this checks for all the 'yada.*'
        $html = preg_replace('/(<'.$element.'\b.+'.$attr.'='."'".')(?!http)([^"]*)('."'".'.*>)/', '$1'.$prepend.'$2$3$4', $html);
        return $html;
    }
}
```

I want my function to work regardless how badly formed the img element is.

It must work regardless the position of the src attribute.

The only thing it is supposed to do is to prepend the src value with something.

Also note that this preg_replace will not happen if the src value starts with http.

Right now, my code works only if my content is:

```
<div class="preload">
    <img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/like_icon_u10_normal.png" width="1" height="1"></img>
    <img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/read_icon_u12_normal.png" width="1" height="1"/><img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/line_u14_line.png" width="1" height="1"/><img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/line_u15_line.png" width="1" height="1"/>
```

As you probably can guess, it successfully does it but only for the first img element because it goes to the next line and there is no / at the end of the opening img tag.

Please advise how to improve my function.

**UPDATE:**

I used DOMDocument and it worked a treat!
After prepending the src values, I need to replace it with a php code snippet

So original:

```
<img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/read_icon_u12_normal.png" width="1" height="1"/>
```

After using DOMDocument and adding my prepend string:

```
<img src="prepended/PRODUCTPAGE_files/read_icon_u12_normal.png" width="1" height="1" />
```

Now I need to replace the whole thing with:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->img('prepended/PRODUCTPAGE_files/read_icon_u12_normal.png', array('width'=>'1', height='1')); ?>
```

Can I still use DOMDocument? Or I need to use preg_replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DomDocument was built to parse HTML no matter how messed up it is, rather then building your own HTML parser, why not use it ?

With a combination of `DomDocument` and `XPath` you can do it like this:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<script src="test"/><link href="test"/><div class="preload"><img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/like_icon_u10_normal.png" width="1" height="1"/><img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/read_icon_u12_normal.png" width="1" height="1"/><img src="PRODUCTPAGE_files/line_u14_line.png" width="1" height="1"/><img width="1" height="1" src="httpPRODUCTPAGE_files/line_u14_line.png"/>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$searchTags = $xpath->query('//img | //link | //script');

$length = $searchTags->length;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $element = $searchTags->item($i);

    if ($element->tagName == 'link')
        $attr = 'href';
    else
        $attr = 'src';

    $src = $element->getAttribute($attr);
    if (!startsWith($src, 'http'))
    {
        $element->setAttribute($attr, "whatever" . $src);
    }
}

// this small function will check the start of a string 
// with a given term, in your case http or http://
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return !strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle));
}

$result = $doc->saveHTML();
echo $result;
```

**[Here is a Live DEMO of it working.](https://eval.in/36394)**

If your HTML if messed up like missing ending tags, etc, you can use before `@$doc->loadHTML($html);`:

```
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
```

If you want the output formatted you can use before `@$doc->loadHTML($html);`:

```
$doc->formatOutput = true;
```

With XPath, we are only capturing the data you need to edit so we don't worry about other elements.

Keep in mind that if your HTML had missing tags for example `body`, `html`, `doctype`, `head` this will automatically add it however if you already had em it shouldn't do anything else.

However if u want to remove them you can use the below instead of just `$doc->saveHTML();`:

```
$result = preg_replace('~<(?:!DOCTYPE|/?(?:html|head|body))[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $doc->saveHTML());
```

---

If you want to replace the element with a new created element on it's place, you can use this:

```
$newElement = $doc->createElement($element->tagName, '');
$newElement->setAttribute($attr, "prepended/" . $src);
$myArrayWithAttributes = array ('width' => '1', 'height' => '1');
foreach ($myArrayWithAttributes as $attribute=>$value)
    $newElement->setAttribute($attribute, $value);
$element->parentNode->replaceChild($newElement, $element);
```

---

By creating a fragment:

```
$frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML('<?php echo $this->Html->img("prepended/PRODUCTPAGE_files/read_icon_u12_normal.png", array("width"=>"1", "height"=>"1")); ?>');
$element->parentNode->replaceChild($frag, $element);
```

**[Live DEMO.](https://eval.in/36488)**

---

You can format the HTML with **[tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)**:

```
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($result, array(
    'indent' => TRUE,
    'output-xhtml' => TRUE,
    'indent-spaces' => 4
));
$tidy->cleanRepair();
echo $tidy;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! it worked a treat, but I now realize that my project requires me to replace the img and link elements with php code snippet after the prepending is done. Any advice? See question for UPDATE

Comment: @kimsia the only difference I see is the `prepended/` which you can do with what I proposed on the above code as `$element->setAttribute($attr, "whatever" . $src);` by changing `"whatever"` to `"prepended/"`.

Comment: @kimsia see my update on how to create a new element and replace an old one at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: in my update, I am not creating a new HTML element. I need to replace it with php code snippet. Any ideas?

Comment: As you can see on the sample I posted above this line `$element->parentNode->replaceChild($newElement, $element);` replaces the old element with new element.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to replace the HTML code with PHP code. I tried exactly with replaceChild. It failed. My insistence in using PHP code is because of cache-busting reasons.

Comment: @kimsia you have to use single quotes around your code otherwise it will get executed if you want to save the code into it without making the code execute. For example: `echo '<?php echo $this->Html->img("prepended/PRODUCTPAGE_files/read_icon_u12_normal.png", array("width"=>"1", "height"=>"1")); ?>';`

Comment: I keep getting Argument  passed to DOMNode::replaceChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given error. Could you try it out to confirm this?

Comment: @kimsia yes because you need to make it a node for example see my new update at the bottom using fragment

Comment: Thank you. It worked for half the nodes. I am not sure why. Anyway, I also couldn't find a tool to prettify the HTML code that has PHP code snippet in them. I have to mix automation with manual effort. :( Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I did. It only works for HTML content. Not a mixture of both :(